# Python (pyspark) Error = ValueError: could not convert string to float: "17"

Tags: python, apache-spark, type-conversion, bigdata

I am working with Python on Spark and reading my dataset from a .csv file whose first a few rows are:

```
17  0.2  7
17  0.2  7
39  1.3  7
19   1   7
19   0   7
```

When I read from the file line by line with the code below:

```
# Load and parse the data
def parsePoint(line):
   values = [float(x) for x in line.replace(',', ' ').split(' ')]
   return LabeledPoint(values[0], values[1:])
```

I get the this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in parsePoint
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "17"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should be using `.split('|')`, not `.split(' ')`

Comment: I put those '|' characters to clarify the borders of the cells while posting my question. They do not exist in the actual file.

Comment: Ah, well the whitespace should do that.  Just put the text into your question exactly how it is in the file.

Comment: I will keep that in mind next time. Thanks.

Comment: Could you [edit] the question then?

Comment: I didn't know how to. Thanks for the hyperlink.

Comment: It's right below all of the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments below this answer, you should use:

```
[float(x.strip(' "')) for x in line.split(',')]
```

You do not need to replace `','` with `' '`, you should simply `split` on `,` and then remove leading and trailing whitespaces and quotes (`x.strip(' "')`) before converting to `float`.

Also, have a look at the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) packages which may simplify your work.

---

*Below is the answer to the original question (before comments).*

You need to use `.split()` instead of `.split(' ')`. You have multiple consecutive space characters in your line, so splitting on `' '` results in empty strings, e.g. your first line is split into:

```
['17', '', '0.2', '', '7']
```

The problem are those empty strings that you (obviously) cannot convert to `float`.

Using `split()` will solve the problem thanks to the behaviour of `split` when its `sep` argument is `None` (or not present):

> If the optional second argument sep is absent or None, the words are separated by arbitrary strings of whitespace characters (space, tab, newline, return, formfeed).

See the doc of [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split), and a small example to understand the difference:

```
>>> sp5 = ' ' * 5
>>> sp5.split()
[]
>>> sp5.split(' ')
['', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Comment: I tried exactly as you said. Now, the same error except that it complains about another value which is 35.
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in parsePoint
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "35"`

Comment: @EmreBulut Could you show the line where this `35` is?

Comment: The file has more than 1 million rows. I do not know which 35 it is complaining about.. 
I opened the file with a text editor this time:
"35","1.3","7"

"29","1","7"

"24","1.2","7"

"24","1.1","7"

"19","0","7"
"36","0","7"
"19","1.2","7"
"24","1.3","7"

Comment: @EmreBulut One good idea to find the line could be to wrap your code into a try such as: `try: [float(x) for x in line.replace(',', ' ').split(' ')]; except ValueError: print(line); exit(1)`.

Comment: @EmreBulut But it looks like your values are wrapped between `"` characters?

Comment: Yes, when I open the file with a text editor it is shown in `"` characters. If I use Gnumeric, it is shown in cells.. I guess the text editor shows the correct version..

Comment: @EmreBulut Try using `float(x.strip('"'))` instead of `float(x)` then

Comment: Good news is that I found the line with try except block as you suggested.
Here is the line:
`"35","0.1","5"`

Comment: You should try the following: `[float(x.strip(' "')) for x in line.split(',')]`, but a probably better solution would be to use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) package since it looks like you are reading CSV files.

Comment: Wow! It worked like a charm! Thanks a lot. I appreciate your help! (I had mentioned that it was a CSV file in the post) I don't know how to accept your comment as the answer. Please guide me about that too :)

Comment: @EmreBulut You cannot accept comments as answer, but I have updated my answer so feel free to accept it if it solves your problem.